# Confusion about Neumann ordinals and power sets

Tags: logic, set-theory

As I was looking at the von Neumann ordinals and their construction, I got slightly confused at the meaning of power sets in this context.

These are the first few:
[Neumann ordinals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoiup.png)

What I don't understand is, a power set is the set of all subsets of a set, right? Consider V3. It is the set containing all subsets of V2 {{}, {{}} } (I denote the empty set by {}). One subset is {}, obviously. This is contained in V3. Another one is {{}}. This is also contained. Another one is the set V2 itself, this too is contained.

So far so good. But it seems to me like {{{}}} should also be a subset. The definition of a subset is that every element of the subset is also included in the original set. The only element contained in the aforementioned subset is {{}}, the set containing the empty set. That set is also contained in V2. So why isn't it included in V3?

Comment: Who said that the ordinals are power sets?

Comment: You’re confusing von Neumann ordinals with the [von Neumann hierarchy of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe).

Comment: I am reading in Yuri Manin's A Course in Mathematical Logic for Mathematicians that the von Neumann ordinals are constructed from successively applying the power set operation on the empty set.

Comment: Whoops, Brian Scott is right.

Comment: Yep, I thought they were the same so I confused myself. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AndreasC: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Well, turns out I confused von Neumann hierarchy of sets with von Neumann ordinals. The book I was reading only included the first couple and I looked online to confirm what I thought would be the rest but I erroneously searched for von Neumann ordinals instead of what I was actually looking for, hence the confusion.